# Does every smooth surface contain three congruent curves?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Let $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a smooth, connected, closed surface. We say a family of smooth curves on $M$ are congruent if each of them can be mapped to  any other by a isometry of the ambient Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$.

**Question:** For every $M$ as above, does there always exist a family of three congruent smooth curves?

*Remark: An elementary argument shows that one can always find (many) pairs of congruent curves. Namely, by applying any isometry $T$ to the ambient $\mathbb R^3$, one obtains a pair of congruent curves from any intersection of $M$ and $T(M)$, so long as these do not correspond to copies of the same curve.*

Comment: One idea to attack the problem: for any $p\in M$ and any isometry $i:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ with $i(p)\in M$ there is a unique curve (or "germ" of a curve) $\gamma_{p,i}$ based at $p$ such that $i\circ\gamma_{p,i}\subseteq M$. So it would be enough if we have a surface $M$ such that $\gamma_{p,i}$ is not isometric to $\gamma_{q,j}$ if $(p,i)\neq(q,j)$ (under some definition of isometry of germs of curves). That seems feasible because there are lots of curves $\gamma$ and not so many $p,i$. 

(One problem: $\gamma_{p,i}$ may not be defined if $i(M)$ is not transversal to $M$ at $i(p)$)

Comment: When Robert Heinlein was a midshipman at the Naval Academy, he took an English course in which on each day, students were presented with some fact situation about which they then had to write one sentence. If the instructor could think of a way in which a reasonable person might misunderstand the sentence, then the student got no credit for that day. And here we have the conspicuously ambiguous subject line of this question: "Does any smooth surface contain three congruent curves?" Does that mean$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$"Is there any smooth surface that contains three congruent curves?" or "Is it true that any smooth surface, no matter which one, contains three congruent curves?"?

Comment: In one case it's an existential quantifier $“\,\exists\,”$ and in the other case a universal quantifier $“\,\forall\,”$.

Comment: English-speaking mathematicians use the word "any" too much. Just changing "any" to "every" would disambiguate it.

Comment: I’ve changed the title.

Comment: Suppose the surface is the skin of a dimpled, hairy and lopsided potato — how would one find the three curves?

Comment: @MattF. I had that idea too, however was unsure of how to make it rigorous.

Comment: Or: Consider an irregular tetrahedron like $(0,0,0),(0,1,2),(3,0,0),(0,4,0)$. Are there three planes whose slices of the tetrahedron are congruent triangles? That is a discrete and decidable question, and it might shed light on the smooth question here.